# Segfault while malloc in C structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm observing `segmentation fault`, when I try to allocate memory to a structure.

After `memcpy()` I'm trying to copy the contents of one more structure to the above structure.

Below is the code snippet :

```
struct student {
    char *username;
    char *id;
    int roll;
};

struct db {
    struct student *s1;
    struct student *s2;
};

void print_struct(struct student *);

int main (void) {
    struct student *student1, *student2;
    struct db *db1;
    char *name = "ram";
    char *id = "200ABCD";
    int roll = 34;

    student1 = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    student1->username = name;
    student1->id = id;
    student1->roll = roll;

    printf("\nStudent 1\n");
    print_struct(student1);

    printf("\nStudent 2\n");
    student2 =student1;
    print_struct(student2);

    printf("\nDb of s1\n");
    db1->s1 = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));  ===> segfault here
    db1->s1 = student1;
    print_struct(db1->s1);

    return 0;
}

void print_struct(struct student *s) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", s->username);
    printf("Id: %s\n", s->id);
    printf("R.No: %d\n", s->roll);
    return;
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: What memcpy? Where?

Answer (score 4):

At the top of your `main` function you declared `db1` as:

```
struct db *db1;
```

It is a not initialized pointer, so you must allocate memory for the pointed `struct db` before dereference to its members:

```
db1 = malloc(sizeof(struct db));
if (db1 != NULL)
{
   db1->s1 = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
}
```

Moreover take notes that malloc & co. can fail: **always check thier returned value**

Lastly you are trying to allocate space for `st1` in `db1` struct, but just after that you are overwriting (memory leak) the pointer using:

```
db1->s1 = student1;
```

Comment: I think you missed to mention about the "variable" at the very beginning. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Probably I need coffee: I'm not getting you..

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear...`You must allocate the struct db` is not proper, you need to mention about the variable `db1` of type `struct db`..inn'it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Got it. Hope my bad English it's clear enough ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your code is inconsistent. See for yourself.

In first case, you did

```
student1 = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));

 /* Considering malloc success, 'student' points to valid memory */

student1->username = name;    //
student1->id = id;            //all the access are OK
student1->roll = roll;        //
```

but later, you did

```
db1->s1 = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));  
db1->s1 = student1;

/* Wait, how do you know 'db' points to anything valid, at all? */
```

without allocating proper memory for `db`.

That said, if you're going to *assign* another pointer to a pointer, you don't need to reserve memory for the destination pointer. You're just making the pointer to point to something already *valid* (depending on the "validity" of the source pointer).

In case you're trying to use the memory location directly (read to or write from) pointed to by any pointer (example, destination of `strcpy()`) without any prior assigment, then you need to allocate memory first.

**Obligatory suggestions:**

- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
- Always check the returned pointer against NULL to ensure `malloc()` is success before using the returned pointer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate memory for `db1` (through `malloc`) first, then its elements.